# What is the best way to quantify concordance of two tests?

Tags: chi-squared-test, proportion, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

I have two different medical diagnostic tests, both test the same condition (binary outcome). The condition in question is rather vaguely defined, so they don't always agree. What would be the best way to quantify the "degree of concordance" between the two tests?

Comment: If the *condition* is vaguely defined, the issue then is not about the agreement between the tests, but what they are calibrated to detect. Poor eGFR and poor creatinine clearance are two indicators of CKD, both indicate related but not identical ways in which the kidneys are failing. Which test is "right" or "better" depends greatly upon the intended purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [Cohen's Kappa](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82162/kappa-statistic-in-plain-english) is a well known measure with good properties that assesses the interrater agreement of two medical tests of a binary outcome.