# Why weighted F1-measure, precision and recall are always very similar to accuracy in my problem?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, model-evaluation, metric

I'm adopting accuracy and macro and weighted averages of precision, recall and f-measure for evaluating my model in a multiclass problem with an imbalanced dataset.

However, I noticed that weighted f1, precision, and recall are always very similar in this context. Is it common? Is it a good practice only use accuracy and macro averages, without weighted averages? Are there scenarios where is justified using weighted averages of precision, recall and f-measure?

Comment: If you post very closely related questions, *please* link them together, which makes life much easier on later people who are interested in the topic. Your first question was [Is accuracy enough for evaluating models in balanced multiclass problems?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/610930/1352), your second question was [Are precision, recall and f-measure more informative than accuracy in multiclass classification with balanced data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/610992/1352)

Comment: Also, please explain how the weighting in your F1 score works, and how precisely you define precision and recall in the multiclass context. Thank you!

Comment: In what sense are they "similar"?

Comment: I'm using these definitions of accuracy, precision and recall and macro and weighted averages.
https://towardsdatascience.com/micro-macro-weighted-averages-of-f1-score-clearly-explained-b603420b292f

Comment: They are very similar in the sense that sometimes the numbers are exactly the same, and sometimes thy differ only in the second decimal digit.

Comment: I posted as a separate question because for me it is a different question.

Comment: But the question remains...Why accuracy is so similar to weighted f1-measure, precision and recall in this problem? Is it common?