# Which metrics to focus on classification problem with imbalanced classes

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes

Currently, I need to work on a binary classification project (e-commerce), where the buyer class (class 1) is a minority class and is the class of interest. Building a classification model has two types of error;

1. predicting as a non-buyer a buyer
2. predicting as a buyer a non-buyer.

For the minority class `class 1`:

> FP means we have predicted 1, while the actual class is 0, i.e. *we classify a non-buyer as a buyer* (precision gets lower).
>
> FN means that we have predicted 0, while the actual class is 1, i.e. *we miss an actual buyer* (recall gets lower).

My question is what metrics I should use to assess different models. Apparently, accuracy is not a very good metric, due to imbalanced classes.

For both classes I will get some metrics, i.e. precision, recall and f1-socre. So where should I focus more?

P.S. Given extra information, that a non-buyer has a small cost and a buyer has some good revenue, would it change the metrics I should focus on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For both classes I will get some metrics, i.e. precision, recall and f1-socre. So where should I focus more?

For binary classification, we usually have one precision and recall / F1 score. and it is usually on "positive" class. Trying to target on improving F1 will be a good practice.

Cohen's Kappa is another good metric for imbalanced problem. Details can be found in this post.

[Cohen's kappa in plain English](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82162/cohens-kappa-in-plain-english)