# Area Under the Precision Recall curve -similar interpretation to AUROC?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, precision-recall

I am trying to interpret the AUCPR. Say I have the following Precision-Recall curve.

Firstly: 
It ends at `0.38` on the y-axis because this particular plot has slightly imbalanced data, so am I correct in thinking its the sum of the positive class / the sum of the negative class.

If I had a negative class of `26300` and a positive class of `10000` then the PR curve would stop at `10000 / 26300 = 0.38`.

Secondly:
In regards to the AUCPR. I understand that perfect accuracy would be a straight line going along the top of the plot but if this curve  had a AUCPR of `0.90` then it would be considered good, however how can I interpret it when the value is perhaps `0.50`, this couldn´t be a random guess like in AUROC since the curve ends at  `0.38`. Is there a way to know when the model becomes worse than flipping a coin?

[image]

Comment: But isn't the AUCPR in that image closer to 0.98?

Comment: Yes probably, I just took a PR curve from the internet and made up a AUCPR

Comment: It’s not total positive over total negative. It’s total positive over total. That’s also the PR curve of the random classifier (the line y = positive prevalence).

Answer (score 5):

The PR curve has a simple geometric interpretation of the expected precision when uniformly varying the recall. It does have a 1-1 correspondence to the ROC curve as shown by Davis & Goadrich (2006) "*[The relation between precision-recall and ROC curves](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jdavis/davisgoadrichcamera2.pdf)*".

A more informative interpretation of AUCPR can be found in Flach & Kill (2015) "*[Precision-Recall-Gain Curves: PR Analysis Done Right](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5867-precision-recall-gain-curves-pr-analysis-done-right.pdf)*". There, the authors present the concept of Precision-Recall-Gain curves, a reformulation of the usual PR curve where the "always positive" classifier serves as the baseline. Following that the AUPRG (Area-Under-the-Precision-Recall-Gain-curve) can be interpreted as the expected [$F_1$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) score.

Regarding the specific side-questions raised:

1. $0.38$ reflects the proportion of positive examples within the training sample. So in the particular case mentioned having $26300$ negative and $10000$ positive examples leads to a base-line of $~0.275$. A more extensive discussion on the baseline of a PR curve can be found in the following CV.SE tread: *[What is "baseline" in precision recall curve](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251175/)*
2. The AUCPR in itself is not very informative. As mentioned it relates to the  expected precision when uniformly varying the recall. In that sense, our model quickly becomes "*worse than flipping a coin*" as we move to more imbalanced datasets; if we know for example that we have a 90-10 imbalance a "fair coin" is bad and it is to our advantage to use a "loaded coin". This is where the work of F&K cited above comes into play; it directly models the *gain* in terms of P-R assuming a "recall-aware" baseline. To that extent, one might want to look at [Cohen's $\kappa$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa) as a quick measurement as it directly accounts for the expected accuracy of a classifier; personally I use almost always when first looking a binary classifier's results. CV.SE has an excellent thread explaining it, in more detail: *[Cohen's kappa in plain English](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82162/cohens-kappa-in-plain-english)*.